# p-trap installation by newbie: cement cure time

Tags: plumbing, cement, p-trap

I was installing a new `p-trap` under the kitchen sink:

[image]

Attached tailpiece to the sink no problem. Then I prepared a short piece of `1 1/2"` ABS pipe, put a plumbing cement on it, inserted one end to the  curvy end of the `p-trap` and the other end (also with cement on it) plugged in to ABS `1 1/2"` adapter (the other end has threads and slip nut, it is put on drain pipe).

So all pieces fit each other well, and I put everything on, opened water to test for leaks for a couple of minutes. At that moment I realized that the cement has to cure long enough before water flows in! I shut it off, and left for 1-2 hours.

Now I'm wondering if all the cement I put on fittings is damaged and has no use. Should I redo my work once again, and give enough time to cure cement?

Thanks.

Comment: The key question: when you _tested_ for leaks did it _actually_ leak? If not, you're fine, if it did, now you know why people tend not to glue in traps, but use ones with hand-tightened slip joints. Nuts are easy to undo/redo. Glue joints, not so much.

Answer (score 2):

It's probably fine. ABS cement hardens in seconds -- probably in less than 20 seconds the joint would be locked up enough that it would not be easily moved by hand.

A joint won't be cured enough to withstand any meaningful amount of water pressure that fast -- a plumber would probably get an unhappy surprise if he cemented test plugs or fittings into place and immediately proceeded to fill a 20-30 foot tall column of water to test a new home's multi-story drain system.

In your case though the pressure would not have exceeded about 1 inch water column. If it didn't leak in your first test, go ahead and test it again. If it continues to not leak that's a good sign that it worked out well enough.

Comment: +1 ABS cement is not so much a cement or glue as it is a catalytic chemical reaction. As soon as you apply it it melts the ABS parts and then allows them to meld together forming what is essentially one solid piece of ABS. As noted, this happens in seconds, much less then 20 in my experience. I am not a fan of "glued" in place ABS P-traps.